# Why can't I view my own deleted questions

Tags: support

I am wondering why I can't view my deleted questions. On some of the other sites I can view them under my profile, by clicking on a link under the list of all the questions I posted on the site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view them. Make sure you are looking at your profile from the main Q&A and not from meta GD.SE.

Here is a link to your main Q&A profile : https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/121452/joselin-jocklingson

Look for highlighted parts under the Questions widget.
[Here is a link to one of your deleted questions if you would like to test it for yourself.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/160044/social-network-for-discussing-the-points-of-view-related-to-human-poses-via-sear)

Comment: Thank you. That was the deleted post I was looking for. However, I am unable to reach it from my main profile. Under questions, there are four questions I posted, but the link to deleted questions does not appear. Perhaps, I'm missing something, line, not seeing something on the page. Can you please post a screenshot with the link to deleted questions. I hereby give you permission to post my profile page, with the link to deleted questions highlighted. Please, post an image, with the link I'm looking for. I'm unable to find it. Thanks.

Comment: Try this link : https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/121452/

Comment: The link works, but how do I get to it from the profile page? What is that 121452 number? Thanks.

Comment: @JoselinJocklingson: It’s linked at the bottom of the [Questions tab](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/121452/joselin-jocklingson?tab=questions). *121452* is your user number.